# LDAP distinguished name validator

Tags: ldap

Is there a library, program or simple regex to check if a DN specified in input is well formed?

Example:
INPUT: manager, ou=company, dc=net ---> OUTPUT: not well formed

INPUT: cn=manager, ou=company, dc=net ---> OUTPUT: well formed

Comment: You could certainly write such a tool based on [the LDAP DN RFC (RFC 4514)](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4514.txt), but accounting for all possible permutations of valid DNs would be difficult at best...

Answer (score 8):

In perl, with `Net::LDAP` it's near trivial:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::LDAP::Util qw/canonical_dn/;
foreach my $dn (@ARGV) {
   if (!defined(canonical_dn($dn))) { print "not well formed: $dn\n"; }
   else                             { print "well formed: $dn\n"; }
}
```

Then:

```
$ perl ldapdn.pl "manager, ou=company, dc=net" "cn=manager, ou=company, dc=net"
not well formed: manager, ou=company, dc=net
well formed: cn=manager, ou=company, dc=net
```

There are a number of functions that validate DNs, `ldap_explode_dn()` might also useful if you wish to normalise and further process DNs.

It's worth noting that "well-formed" and "valid" aren't the same thing, since a syntactically well-formed DN might not match the schema of a particular LDAP DIT, and hence be rejected.

If you have OpenLDAP, any recent version should come with a `slapdn` program. This *does* proper schema checking, but you must have a viable `slapd.conf` and schema set on the system you run it of course (which may require running it as root or a special user due to file permissions on operational configuration files).

```
$ /usr/local/sbin/slapdn  -v "cn=manager, ou=company, dc=net"
DN: <cn=manager, ou=company, dc=net> check succeeded
normalized: <cn=manager,ou=company,dc=net>
pretty:     <cn=manager,ou=company,dc=net>
```

(If you have OpenLDAP built from source, it also comes with a `dntest` program built as part of its test suite. It only parses DNs, no schema checking. Sadly it doesn't have a usable error code, and appears to occasionally indicate malformed DNs with a segfault...)

And finally, the regex approach. As suggested by @voretaq7 you can use the [ABNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) from [RFC 4514](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4514), though you'll also need the base syntaxes from [RFC 4512](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4512) (§1.4). Run those though any ABNF to ERE converter (e.g. [abnf2regex](https://github.com/martinthomson/abnf2regex/wiki), implemented in Java), and out it pops. I'm not going to paste it here, it's approximately 4k of line noise. You can crack the whole nut with `abnf2regex` though:

```
$ java -jar abnf2regex.jar -t distinguishedName \
        "cn=manager,ou=company,dc=net" rfc4512.abnf rfc4514dn.abnf
Rule "distinguishedName" matches: cn=manager,ou=company,dc=net
Rule: [relativeDistinguishedName *(COMMA relativeDistinguishedName)]
Expanded: [(((%x41-5a / %x61-7a) *(%x41-5a / %x61-7a / %x30 / %x31-39 / %x2d))
 ... <<expanded ABNF snipped>>
Regex: (?:(?:[A-Za-z][\-01-9A-Za-z]*|(?:[01-9]|[1-9][01-9]+)(?:\.(?:[01-9]
 ... <<expanded regex snipped>>
```

The above is testing a string against the regex generated from specific named rule (`-t distinguishedName`). If you have sharp eyes you'll notice I cheated just a little, I removed the whitespace from the DN since it's [not technically part of the DN](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4514#appendix-A) and will break the match.

---

And finally (really this time) a *simplified and imperfect* [regex](http://regex101.com/r/sH2zA1) that you can use with [`pcregrep -i`](http://www.pcre.org/):

```
 ^([a-z][a-z0-9-]*)=(?![ #])(((?![\\="+,;<>]).)|(\\[ \\#="+,;<>])|(\\[a-f0-9][a-f0-9]))*
(,([a-z][a-z0-9-]*)=(?![ #])(((?![\\="+,;<>]).)|(\\[ \\#="+,;<>])|(\\[a-f0-9][a-f0-9]))*)*$
```

I have padded and wrapped it to make it legible, well, less illegible perhaps. Simplified breakdown is

```
^(attributename)=(attributevalue)(,(attributename)=(attributevalue))*$
```

with

```
 attributevalue = not leading space or octothorpe |
                  any char except specials | 
                  escaped specials |
                  escaped hex-digit pair
```

This takes *at least* the following liberties:

- it largely ignores Unicode (though you might find `pcregrep --utf` helps) and won't validate UTF-8
- it does not support direct numeric OIDs in attribute types
- it does not support multi-valued RDNs (e.g. `cn=Bob+sn=Smith`)
- it doesn't handle un-escaped trailing  whitespace

As per-spec, it doesn't deal with gratuitous formatting whitespace at the start, end or around ",".

Comment: My word, what an answer: I'm sorry I can only upvote it once.

Answer (score 5):

Don't bother. The LDAP server you're talking too already knows what an invalid DN looks like. Just catch the error (response code) and act on it appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

The openldap library provides this subroutine, I'm not aware of any ldap interfaces for ruby,perl,etc that provide access to this api. But I haven't looked that hard.

```
ldap_str2dn() parses a string representation of  a  distinguished  name
   contained  in  str  into  its  components,  which  are  stored in dn as
   ldap_ava structures, arranged in LDAPAVA, LDAPRDN,  and  LDAPDN  terms,
   defined as:

   typedef struct ldap_ava {
       char *la_attr;
       struct berval *la_value;
       unsigned la_flags;
   } LDAPAVA;
```

Answer (score 0):

I improve my question adding my simple (maybe too simple) alternative-answer: I created a regexp to match all possible dns

`(\w+[=]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9\-\$&\(\)\[\]\{\}\.\s]+)([,{1}]\w+[=]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9\-\(\)\[\]\{\}\.\s]+)*`

Comment: Minor problems with attributetype (missing `-`, extra `_`), won't accept empty values or a few other legitimate characters like `& ' / @`. I've added a slightly more pedantic, but relatively simple example to my answer...